# Find children of children elements with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I've to edit the content and attributes of the `table`. This DOM is provided by a third-party tool and I use JavaScript to edit different parts.

```html
<div id="myId">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>Content I have to edit</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use `document.getElementById('myId').children`, but how can I edit attributes of childrens children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the table:

   ```
   var table = document.querySelector("#myId table");
   ```

   `document.querySelector` takes any valid CSS selector and returns the first match, so the selector is `#myId table`.
2. You can use `document.getElementById` to get the `div`, and then use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) or [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) on that element (rather than `document`) to find the table:

   ```
   var div = document.getElementById("myId");
   var table = div.querySelector("table");
   // Or: var table = div.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
   ```

   (Note the `[0]` on the `getElementsByTagName` version, since what you get is an `HTMLCollection`, not just one element.)

MDN's [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) material is quite good. (More generally, its coverage of [web technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is quite good.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming for whatever reason you can't directly select the table [1], then you can chain `.children[0]`, or better yet `firstElementChild`, calls.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('myId').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

console.log(table);
```

```html
<div id="myId">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>Content I have to edit</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[1] If you can, then `querySelector` as in T.J.'s answer would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

firstElementChild Property returns a DOM Object where you can use the same firstElementChild property. Look at the docmumentation:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_firstelementchild.asp

or if you need a specific item and it is not the first, you need to use the children property:

```
document.getElementById("myId").children[2].children[2]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp